# Create 2 x 2 square inside a picture box

Tags: c#

I am currently starting to build a simple version of the Game of Life following the same logic. I am  using a picture box.  In order to know where an area is clicked, it is advised to use 2 x 2 squares. How can I create 2 x 2 squares and give it a grid like style inside the pictureBox?

**CODE**

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Image = this.Draw(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height);
        }

        public Bitmap Draw(int width, int height)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Tomato), 60, 60, 10, 10);

            return bitmap;
        }
```

EXAMPLE of outlook

[image]

Comment: Please add sample code of what you can do (i.e. draw single point), and than someone will be able to advice on how to draw 2x2.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I forogot, But I have added the sample code.